# Edit, cancel and delete asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

ASPX:
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv_localidad" AutoGenerateColumns="false">

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Modify">
                   <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Editar" OnClick="OnEdit" Visible="true"  />
          <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" Visible="false" />
                 <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Eliminar" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                             </Columns>
                               </asp:GridView>
```

C#:

```
private void BindGrid()
{
  string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString;
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Herramientas", con))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                using (DataTable dtReport = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dtReport);
                    gv_localidad.DataSource = dtReport;
                    gv_localidad.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
protected void OnEdit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (sender as Button).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    int index = row.RowIndex;
    for (int i = 0; i < gv_localidad.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (index == i)
        {
            (gv_localidad.Rows[i].FindControl("btnUpdate") as Button).Visible = true;
            (gv_localidad.Rows[i].FindControl("btnEdit") as Button).Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            (gv_localidad.Rows[i].FindControl("btnEdit") as Button).Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why i ask is because the buttons doesnt even appear. If you wanna see the full class pls tell me, thanks.

Comment: please explains the problem

Comment: See my complete demo how to edit, delete, sort etc a gridview. https://www.vanderwaal.eu/mini-projecten/gridview-edit-and-update-demo. You can download the example from github there.